# Counterexamples for $\alpha < \beta \Longrightarrow \alpha^{\gamma} < \beta^{\gamma}$, where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are nonzero ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to find counterexamples for the following formula:

> $\alpha < \beta \Longrightarrow \alpha^{\gamma} < \beta^{\gamma}$, where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are nonzero ordinals.

I think $\gamma$ may have to be a limit ordinal, for instance, maybe $\omega$ (another notation for $\mathbb{N}$). Can anyone provide hints?

Comment: *Hint*: $n<2^n<3^n<\omega$ for all $0\neq n\in\omega$, so taking sup...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This makes perfectly good sense as a question about ordinals, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hint: let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be finite

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Ordinals are a standard kind of mathematical object, and exponentiation of ordinals is an operation with a standard definition. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) for an introduction!

Comment: 0.7 is not an ordinal, nor did I ever claim it was. I feel you're being quite combative here. The question, as written by OP, does make sense.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: You really ought to stop: you are simply displaying your ignorance of a fundamental concept in set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this proof thanks to hints provided. Consider the following two ordinals: $\boldsymbol{2}^{\omega}$ and $\boldsymbol{3}^{\omega}$. The two ordinals can be expanded as
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{2}^{\omega} = \bigcup\left\{\boldsymbol{2}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\},
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{3}^{\omega} = \bigcup\left\{\boldsymbol{3}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}.
\end{equation*}
It is obvious that $\omega$ is an upper bound for both $\left\{\boldsymbol{2}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}$ and $\left\{\boldsymbol{3}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}$.

Next assume that there exists some ordinal $\lambda$ such that $\lambda < \omega$ and that $\lambda$ is also an upper bound for $\left\{\boldsymbol{2}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}$. Immediately we have $\lambda < \boldsymbol{2}^{\lambda} \in \left\{\boldsymbol{2}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}$, contradicting that $\lambda$ is an upper bound of $\left\{\boldsymbol{2}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}$. Thus, $\omega = \operatorname{lub}\left(\left\{\boldsymbol{2}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}\right)$. Similarly, $\omega = \operatorname{lub}\left(\left\{\boldsymbol{3}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}\right)$. Then we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{2}^{\omega} &= \bigcup\left\{\boldsymbol{2}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}\\
&= \operatorname{lub}\left(\left\{\boldsymbol{2}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}\right)\\
&= \omega\\
&= \operatorname{lub}\left(\left\{\boldsymbol{3}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}\right)\\
&= \bigcup\left\{\boldsymbol{3}^{\theta}: \theta \in \omega\right\}\\
&= \boldsymbol{3}^{\omega}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Yes, this is fine.